# Hint on normal subgroup of dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can compute the subgroups perfectly but I have a challenge in finding the normal subgroups, though I know that I can use either the coset way which says that left coset is equal to right coset or I make use of conjugacy but I don't really understand how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Have you tried to find all the subgroups of $D_3$ or $D_4$ and then determine which are normal using the methods you mention?  (Sometimes these are called $D_6$ or $D_8$.)

Comment: Yes but I just used trial and error, so I want to be sure of my answers, can you help me with concrete examples? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct, {e,a²}, using gNg—¹ = N, I have a.a².a³ = a.(a².a³)= a.a = a² which I assume to be normal and also {e,b} which I worked out to be a.b.a³= (a.b).a³=ba³.a³=ba²=a²b which I assume that it is not normal, I am not sure if I am correct.

Comment: Since you don't say what $a$ and $b$ are, your comment is completely unintelligible to anyone who cannot read your mind.

Comment: I mean using D8 as an example such that D8:= <e,a,a²,a³,b,ab,a²b,a³b>. Then using gHg—¹ = H, for g in G, which is the condition for normal subgroup. Since {e,a²} is the centre of the group and it is normal, my question is that am I correct to find the normal subgroup this way: a.a².a³(that is a³ is the inverse of a in G and a² is a subgroup)= a.(a².a³) =a.a = a² is this how to show for normal subgroup? Also a.b.a³=(ab).a³= ba³.a³ = ba²=a²b which I assume it is not a normal subgroup. Does this make any sense? Thanks

Comment: @Dammy I am a little bit confused on your method of finding normal subgroups. This does not completely answer your question, but we know the dihedral group of order $2n$, $D_{2n}$, has a cyclic subgroup of order $n$. Since this subgroup has index 2 in $D_{2n}$ it is necessarily normal, in your notation this is the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$. Moreoever, any subgroup of a cyclic group is a characteristic subgroup. Hence, any subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$ is also normal in $D_{2n}$ (that is $\langle a^n \rangle$ is normal in $D_{2n}$ for all $n$).

Comment: Thanks.....very useful.

Comment: @ Mike I Just want to learn more on Dihedral group and how to classify the distinct normal subgroup by a new equivalence relation, any right up will be well appreciated, more so you can as well help with concrete examples. thanks